# python split string from file

Tags: python, string, split

Im kinda new to python, im trying to the basic task of splitting string data from a file using a double backslash (\\) delimiter. Its failing, so far:

```
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import string
    import os

    #remove previous finalhostlist
    try:
        os.remove("finalhostlist.txt")
    except Exception as e: 
      print (e)

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    print ("choose hostname target list")
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    with open("finalhostlist.txt", "wt") as rawhostlist:
        with open(file_path, "rt") as finhostlist:
            for line in finhostlist:
##            rawhostlist.write("\n".join(line.split("\\\\")))
              rawhostlist.write(line.replace(r'\\', '\n'))
```

I need the result to be from e.g. 
 `\\Accounts01\\Accounts02` 
 to 
`Accounts01
Accounts02`

Can someone help me with this? I'm using python 3.

**EDIT**: All good now, `strip("\\")` on its own did it for me.

Thanks guys!

Comment: So what do you expect to be written? You have a list of strings, your split succeeded.

Comment: Why are you importing tkinter two different ways? Also, you have an indentation error.

Comment: oh that was before I fixed it.  thanks for pointing it out. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write expects a string and you have passed it a list, if you want the contents written use `str.join`.

```
rawhostlist.write("\n".join(line.split("\\")))
```

You also don't need to call close when you use `with`, it closes your file automatically and you actually never call close anyway as you are missing parens `rawhostlist.close -> rawhostlist.close()`

It is not clear if you actually have 2,3 or 4 backslashes. Your original code has two, your edit has three so whichever it is you need to use to same amount to split.

```
In [66]: s = "\\Accounts01\\Accounts02"
In [67]: "\n".join(s.split("\\\\"))
Out[67]: '\\Accounts01\\Accounts02'    
In [68]: s = "\\\Accounts01\\\counts02"    
In [69]: "\n".join(s.split("\\\\"))
Out[69]: '\nAccounts01\ncounts02'
```

If it varies then split with `\\` and filter empty strings.

Looking at the file you posted, you have a single element on each line so simply use strip

```
with open("finalhostlist.txt", "wt") as f_out, open(infile, "rt") as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            out.write(line.strip("\\"))
```

Output:

```
ACCOUNTS01    
EXAMS01
EXAMS02                                                        
RECEPTION01
RECEPTION02
RECEPTION03
RECEPTION04
RECEPTION05
TEACHER01  
TEACHER02                                                            
TEACHER03
TESTCENTRE-01        
TESTCENTRE-02
TESTCENTRE-03  
TESTCENTRE-04  
TESTCENTRE-05  
TESTCENTRE-06  
TESTCENTRE-07  
TESTCENTRE-08  
TESTCENTRE-09  
TESTCENTRE-10  
TESTCENTRE-11  
TESTCENTRE-12  
TESTCENTRE-13  
TESTCENTRE-14  
TESTCENTRE-15
```

Comment: This just writes out the elements *concatenated*. `file.writelines()` doesn't add newlines in between. That may be fine, but it is far from clear what the expected output is, really.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is giving me a strange output though :( `\\ACCOUNTS01
,,"ACCOUNTS01`                                                                   
"  and lots of " and .end of file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hey, its better! but still... im getting an output with duplicate entries, like so [here](http://pastebin.com/fffCb6QM)

Comment: ah thanks, it works now. However, it is also making double empty lines between entries, would there be a way to remove them?

Comment: It's "double new lining" because you forgot to escape the \ character, @PadraicCunningham. You would need to do ```.split('\\\\')```, or just use a raw string literal by prefacing the string with the r flag (```.split(r'\\')```). On another note, there is no reason to ```.split()``` the string just to ```.join()``` it; see my answer.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, please explain.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But OP is asking for splitting by \\, so you need to escape BOTH of those slashes, leading to ```'\\\\'``` or ```r'\\'```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73628/discussion-between-pzp1997-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: @pzp1997,   the OP's input was added with an edit, it does not match what the have shown in the output added in a comment, also without adding a newline at the end all the output will be in one line

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Whatever, I see we aren't going to agree on this point. It seems that this disagreement arose from the fact that each one of us in interpreting the question differently. It all depends on how many slashes the OP wants. Still don't know why you'd waste the memory to construct the list though, just to concatenate it back into a string.

Comment: @pzp1997, because that is what the OP's code was doing long before you answered, the questions has been edited a few times. Your code will also fail unless there are exactly the same amount of `"\\"` so splitting and filtering may be the only solution but without being a mind reader or seeing all the data it is kind of hard to tell. Also splitting a couple of words or using replace is not exactly going to matter much in this example, we are talking nanoseconds. To be honest I am not sure the OP fully knows what is happening in the code.

Comment: Well, from what I understood so far, ``\\`` is also an escape character in formatting strings, not the ideal delimiter to have. So in the code you need to ensure it reads delimiter as ``\\``. Oh I did not see my edit had three backslashes! meant to be just two backslashes, sorry about the confusion... so for every double backslash, create newline. will edit again.. Both answers including @pzp1997 's results in a exactly the same output. `A \n \n B`, the extra `\n` means there's now one empty line between entries [like so](http://pastebin.com/Eph6tbjv)

Comment: You have single lines of data, why are you splitting at all?

Answer (score 1):

I would do `rawhostlist.write(line.replace(r'\\', '\n'))`. If you want a little more efficiency feel free to use `re.sub()` instead, but I don't think it will make much of a difference here. There's no need to call `.write()` for each line. And there is definitely no need to convert the string into a list -- just to convert it back into a string!

Answer (score 0):

if you want them written on separate lines:

```
   for sub in line.split("\\"):rawhostlist.write(sub)
```

Comment: This one gets rid of `\\` but duplicates on the same line,  \\ACCOUNTS01ACCOUNTS01                                                                   
\\EXAMS01EXAMS01